# Who excels under pressure?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

I am not looking for phrases that mean to keep your poise or have courage.

I am looking for something - word or phrase - the succinctly describes someone who is better under pressure.

An example would be a basketball player who shoots 3 pointers 35% overall but if he has a guy in his face he shoots 45% and if he has a guy in his face and in a close game in the 4th quarter he shoots over 50%.  Is there something that summarizes the relationship between more pressure and more performance?

**Edit:**  Clutch is a really good term and we had thought about using that.  We need a term t:that fits into our database model for football/basketball advanced metrics.  Was looking for something that is a little more scientific and not a current cliche but if the shoe fits we will use it.  Still open to more suggestions.

Comment: Me! I excel under pressure! XD

Comment: A steam engine (locomotive)

Comment: A bookkeeper.  Bada bing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A player who doesn't [buckle under](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/buckle+under) pressure, could be said to [deliver the goods](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/deliver+the+goods). And I would also describe such a player as being *ruthless* and *consistent*.

However, a slang term which fits the Op's request is **clutch**:
[to perform under pressure](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clutch)
*In the last few seconds of a close game, only a player with clutch can lead the team to victory. (Derived from the clutch mechanism in a manual car, where perfect timing can mean the difference between a launch and a stall)*

A reputable baseball coach has this to say: <sup>[1](http://www.hsbaseballweb.com/under_pressure.htm)</sup>

> If a hitter is averaging .333 and gets a hit one time in three clutch
>   situations, he is performing well **in the clutch**... normal performance
>   under pressure is the goal, not super performance.
>
> All too often an athlete gets the reputation as a "**great clutch
>   player**" because of one or two performances that got a lot of media
>   attention, but the truth of the matter is most of the time a "great
>   clutch performer" is one who performs normally under pressure.

Comment: Balotelli's missed a couple now. Matt Le Tissier is an even better example :-)

Comment: Ahh, has he? I checked on Wikipedia and it mentioned the one failed penalty. Still has an impressive track record though.

Comment: http://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/football/news/mario-balotelli-declares-this-end-2846654

Comment: @SteveJessop Penalty scored 83' by Balotelli http://www.gazzetta.it/Calcio/Squadre/Milan/19-01-2014/milan-verona-1-0-gol-balotelli-rigore-finale-parte-bene-seedorf-202116577605.shtml The headline's in Italian but easy enough to deduce.

Comment: "Balotelli in 'exaggerated reaction to misfortune' shock"

Comment: Not "a player with clutch", but "a clutch player".

Comment: @user2619   I limited myself to copying and pasting the definition from UD but, admittedly, the baseball coach also mentions a "great clutch player" in the article, so thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Clutch is a really good answer and the best I came up with on my own.  I would get rid of the rest though.  Potatoes are covering the meat.

Comment: +1 for _clutch_, though I think _ruthless_ would only apply in limited contexts. As an interesting side note, [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/clutch?q=clutch) gives this definition, with the tag `U.S.`: _achieving or characterized by success at a critical moment in a game or competition_. Yet it also says: (also `British` **clutch up**) _Become nervous and panicked:
doctors could clutch up and lose control as easily as anyone_. I suppose, then, that _clutch_ could be considered an autoantonym, but I still think it's the clutch answer here.

Answer (score 2):

Consider

> - rise to the occasion
> - rise to the challenge
> - step up
> - thrive in a crisis
> - thrive on adversity

If the player or team were doing poorly and then rallied, you could say

> come back from the dead

Comment: thrive and rise are great words here.  Not sure I will find the perfect phrase but all of yours are good.

Answer (score 0):

How about **pressure hitter** and [**pressure performer**](http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1290&dat=19940913&id=D1FUAAAAIBAJ&sjid=to4DAAAAIBAJ&pg=6720,6908818)?

> *Nick Folk, Jets kicker, says he knows he has what it takes to be a pressure performer in postseason*. [My Daily News](http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/football/jets/nick-folk-jets-kicker-takes-pressure-performer-postseason-article-1.152444)

Comsider also the phrases **work wonders** (or ***outperform oneself***) **when pressure is full on** and **be at one's best when pressure is at its highest**.

Comment: The author should have asked my question before using that phrase.  I get it but that is low end succinctness.

Answer (score 0):

'When the going gets tough, the tough get going' is a famous modern proverb.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite there, but may fit in certain context,

Resilient

or

Irrepressible

Answer (score 0):

Or the one that was on the tip of my tongue,

Indefatigable.

To give, indefatigable under duress.

Answer (score 0):

difficult, but perhaps pressure-stimulated or pressure-driven. I like pressure-stimulated as it give the connotation of being pulled rather than pushed like pressure-driven. "stimulated" gives the impression of positivity in that pressure enhances performance which already exists, while driven gives the impression that performance occurs only while driven. just my impression.