# One word for scientist who can deal with pressure

Tags: single-word-requests

As I am writing down my [CV](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/cv/), there is a part where I am saying that I can deal with pressure and there are proofs about it.

So, I would like to squeeze that information in one line. As a result a word for replacing:

**Able to deal with pressure** = 'one word'

If it helps, I am in Computer Science. Relevant question for football: [Who excels under pressure?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163302/who-excels-under-pressure)

<sub>Wish I could summon an Ancient Spartan, which would find the laconic way into this, without having to trouble you</sub>

Comment: maybe resilient? :)

Comment: You should totally use "unflappable".

Comment: "baryspheric" .

Comment: The two first comments suggest good candidates. However, in just a glance they seem equally good to me. Please post an answer providing an example maybe. @GregLee is that a valid word? Google translate cannot find it and I only understand it because I am Greek.

Comment: I was mostly joking with mine gsamaras. Although unflappable does mean "having or showing calmness in a crisis." it's probably too informal for a CV.

Comment: When you said *totally* I thought of that.. :/ @JohnClifford (fun is always good if it leaves you with a smile) ;)

Comment: @gsamaras, presumably "baryspheric" is a word, since "barysphere" is.  See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barysphere .

Comment: OK that makes sense @GregLee, I suspect it will be an error of Google translate. However, I am not sure I can see the link with the question.

Comment: @gsamaras, the interior of the earth is a high-pressure environment.

Comment: Cool @GregLee. So `resilient` vs `baryspheric`.

Comment: Uh, I hope it's clear that I was kidding.

Comment: Oh, OK..It was nice though :)

Comment: I would think "hydraulic engineer" would fit.

Comment: "determined  and disciplined" (or resolute and rigourous) : 2 virtues allowing to work under pressure.

Comment: CV's can get pompous.  Just say it, that you can deal with pressure. "unflappable", "baryspheric(?)" and "resilient" might engender laughs where I work.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան I accepted an answer, but if you would like to provide an answer with **resilient**, *please* go ahead, because it is a very good option!!!

Comment: Isn't the cliche to claim that you're *driven under pressure*?

Comment: I can prove that @Mazura and I really wish the recruiter to ask me why I am claiming this. I am sure that I have 1.5 stories that he haven't heard. :)

Comment: The 'scientist' allusion is not helpful here. Answers will be equally applicable to doctors, salespersons, explorers ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Equanimity* should do the trick. Sentence:

> While under pressure to complete your CV, you have approached the problem with equanimity.

Answer (score 2):

Consider **imperturbable**, which *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) defines as follows:

> **imperturbable** *adj* (15c) : marked by extreme calm, impassivity, and steadiness: SERENE

Note that *impassivity* is very different from *passivity*; it is far closer in sense to "maintaining a poker face, refraining from showing any emotion" (my wording). In distinguishing *imperturbable* from similar adjectives, the *Eleventh Collegiate* says this:

> IMPERTURBABLE implies coolness or assurance even under severe provocation. {the speaker remained *imperturbable* despite the heckling}.

Other synonyms that the dictionary suggests are *composed* (in the sense of maintaining composure), *collected*, *unruffled*, and *cool* (under fire).

Answer (score 1):

Since we're talking about science, you might consider **'homeostatic;'** its meaning is what you're looking for, and it's obviously a scientific term as well as a personality descriptor.

But for a resume, I really like the word **'unshakable:'** it sounds very dynamic and cool, whereas words like 'poised' sound too graceful, and words like 'imperturable' and 'composed' make you sound nerdy or robotic.

(And by the way, the commenter who wrote 'clutch' for the excel-under-pressure football usage, in my opinion, nailed the three-pointer.)

Comment: So you would write `unshakable` versus `clutch`, right?

Comment: For sure in this case. "Clutch" is strictly a sports-related word.

Comment: You'd only use "clutch" if you knew you were giving the resume to a) a sports fan, and b) a person with a sense of humor, because it would be a very informal thing to do on a resume.

Answer (score -1):

Unflappable is a choice you could use

Comment: You should include the dictionary definition for your word and explain why it's an answer.